# Use a transparent, click-through form to monitor for activity

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winforms-interop

A client has a problem with employees opening a program displaying sensitive information and walking away without closing it. They've asked me to monitor when the application is open and close it after a certain amount of inactivity.

What I've done is created a new program that launches the original, but with another form on top of it.  If my form is transparent, I can click through the form with no problems, and manipulate the underlying program. If my form is (slightly) opaque, clicks will register with my program, but will not pass through.

What I need is a way to let my form register that a click has happened, reset its timer, and pass the click through to the underlying application.  I can reset the timer, or I can pass the click through, but not both.

Here's the code I'm currently trying. The first section defines my form as transparent and keeps it on top of the other application.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity = 0.40;
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
```

I thought this would let me monitor for a click, reset the timer, then pass it through, but it's not working, so I must be missing something.  EDIT: WT_NCHITTEST = 0x84, and HTTRANSPARENT = -1, as indicated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST) // m.Msg 0x84 means that Windows is asking our form whether it is "transparent" or not.
        {
            timeToClose = 10;
            m.Result = new IntPtr(HTTRANSPARENT); // tell Windows yes, to pass everything through.
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: This seems somewhat long-winded. Why not capture mouse clicks (etc) on your top level window rather than creating a "proxy"-layer?

Comment: You are asking for the wrong way to implement this feature.  It is much simpler than that.  Including and not limited to asking your client to solve this problem, trivial as well, so his security problem doesn't become yours.

Comment: I'm wondering how this fixes the problem? This should be an IT policy that locks the workstation after some activity, pretty simple to do with security policies.

Comment: @spender, I'm not sure what you mean by that. The application in question isn't my company's, so I can't do it directly.@hans-passant, while that might be the ideal solution, it's not really helpful. The customer asked my company if we could do this, was told yes, and has contracted to pay my company for doing so. Turning around and saying, "Well, you could just tell your people to close the program" isn't really ideal for business.

Comment: If you don't have source code, you're probably better off injecting a DLL and monitor for inputs directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is way over engineered, I implement inactivity checks with System.Timers.Timer and PInvoke GetLastInputInfo.  Run a second application that monitors for workstation inactivity and close sensitive applications when the threshold is violated.

Initialize the timer with an interval and set it to auto-reset, then just check for inactivity every time the timer elapses.  If the inactivity time is greater than your threshold, shut it down.

Here is the code for GetLastInputInfo.

```
public static class Tracker
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to the GetLastInputInfo in the user32.dll file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="plii">LASTINPUTINFO struct</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetLastInputInfo(ref LASTINPUTINFO plii);

    /// <summary>
    /// Polls the system for the milliseconds elapsed since last user input.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Milliseconds since last user input.</returns>
    public static uint GetIdleTime()
    {
        LASTINPUTINFO lastInput = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInput.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInput);
        GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInput);

        return ((uint)Environment.TickCount - lastInput.dwTime);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Struct required and populated by the user32.dll GetLastInputInfo method.
/// </summary>
internal struct LASTINPUTINFO
{
    public uint cbSize; //Size of the struct.
    public uint dwTime; //TickCount at last input.
}
```

My inactivity timer implementation looks like this:

```
public void InitializeTimer()
{
    ActivityTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(Configuration.TimeoutSettings["IntervalMilliseconds"]);
    ActivityTimer.AutoReset = true;
    ActivityTimer.Elapsed += OnElapsedPollForActivity;
    ActivityTimer.Start();
}

/// <summary>
/// Method is called in ValidationForm_FormClosing, unsubscribes handler from event and stops the clock.
/// </summary>
public void TerminateTimer()
{
    ActivityTimer.Elapsed -= OnElapsedPollForActivity;
    ActivityTimer.Stop();
}

/// <summary>
/// Fires on ActivityTimer.Elapsed, polls workstation for time since last user input.
/// </summary>
private void OnElapsedPollForActivity(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Tracker.GetIdleTime() > Configuration.TimeoutSettings["TriggerMilliseconds"])
    {
        Logger.LogException(CurrentSession.SessionID, DateTime.Now, new InactivityException("Detected extended period of workstation inactivity."));
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly, and I like that it's using a solution where I don't have to do the overlay. I didn't realize there was another way for me to monitor for inactivity.  I appreciate that you came up with a solution to actually fulfill my client's needs rather than just telling me "they should implement a security policy and not hire you," which, while true, isn't exactly helpful as a business model.